# Selecting default value for ng-options in Angular

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, default, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

I have two dropdowns, one is dependent on the other. I originally had my code using ng-repeat but read that it is more efficient to use ng-options. However, in switching over, I can't use ng-selected for the default any longer.

I've looked at different methods of setting the default option in ng-options but they use either `<option value="">Select Something Here</option>` for a customized option or selecting straight from the dataset. However my value will be changing.

Here is a working plunker using ng-repeat:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ie4VDDlrwSUSqIq7laoa?p=preview

Here is a plunker missing the default using ng-option:

http://plnkr.co/edit/TGoWTMqOuJnWKNTUARWI?p=preview

The default value should be `$scope.defnum` , which is taken from a different dataset than the values in my dropdown, so I want to have the default `DefCom = defnum`. I've tried doing this using ng-init by assigning an original variable in the controller:

```
 $scope.defcom = 4;
 var original_defcom = $scope.defcom;
```

and using `ng-init="original_defcom"` in the template.

and in ng-model, even wrapping it in an `<option>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in the ng-options

```
<select ng-model="defcom"
    ng-options="opt.DefCom as opt.DefCom for opt in acct_info | filter:{Req:'MUST'}:true" >
</select>
```

Then, you have to change de $scope.defcom type to match the array. In the plunker the variable is a Number and the array is full of Strings. You have to change one of them. If I where you, I'd change the type of the properties in the objects in the array. The ng-options parses the numbers automatically.

This is an version of your plunker afters a few changes:

http://plnkr.co/edit/tIeDEC8MxfcvnRrc0Njh?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

try like this.

and change to this :   `$scope.defcom = "4";`

```
 <select ng-model="defcom" ng-options="opt.DefCom as opt.DefCom for opt in acct_info | filter:{Req:'MUST'}:true" >>
```

```js
// Code goes here

angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.test = "This is a test";
    $scope.defcom = "4";
    var original_defcom = $scope.defcom;
    var original_com = $scope.com;
    
    $scope.acct_info = [
      {
        "Req": "MUST",
        "DefCom": "1"
      },
      {
        "Req": "NoMUST",
        "DefCom": "5"
      },
      {
        "Req": "MUST",
        "DefCom": "4"
      },
      {
        "Req": "MUST",
        "DefCom": "7"
      }
    ];
    
    $scope.cust_info = [
      {
        "Customer": "1",
        "Com": "1"
      },
      {
        "Customer": "2",
        "Com": "1"
      },
      {
        "Customer": "3",
        "Com": "4"
      },
      {
        "Customer": "4",
        "Com": "4"
      },
      {
        "Customer": "5",
        "Com": "7"
      },
      {
        "Customer": "6",
        "Com": "7"
      },
      {
        "Customer": "7",
        "Com": "7"
      }
    ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <p>{{ test }}</p>
      <select ng-model="defcom" ng-options="opt.DefCom as opt.DefCom for opt in acct_info | filter:{Req:'MUST'}:true" >>
  </select>
  
    </div>
  </div>
```

`